# Using third-party javascript in MVC

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to call a javascript function that is located in a ~/vendor/ directory (see schema below) without success. If I move that javascript to my directory ~/public/js/ the call succeeds.

I believe my issue might come from my .htaccess files, but I didn't find a way to fix it despite quite some readings. If anybody could point me in the right direction, I'd be very happy.

This is the directory structure (note the .htaccess on root and in public/):

```
<project name>/
    application/
        config/
        controllers/
        models/
        views/
    public/
        css/
        images/
        js/     <- if placed here, the call succeeds
        .htaccess
        index.php
    vendor/
        <third-party code>/
            javascript.js     <- here, it doesn't
    .htaccess
```

And here is the content of the .htaccess files:

- on root directory:

  ```
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
      RewriteEngine on
      RewriteRule    ^$    public/    [L]
      RewriteRule    (.*) public/$1    [L]
   </IfModule>
  ```
- in public directory:

  ```
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
      RewriteEngine On
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
      RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [PT,L]
  </IfModule>
  ```

Comment: Why don't you have a 'public/js/Vendor' folder instead. That would solve your problem.

Comment: Well, yes, only your `public` directory is, well, public, according to those rewrite rules. Change the rules or move the file.

Comment: True, but this vendor also has CSS I would like to use. And it seems cleaner to have everything related to this vendor in one and only one directory instead of having /public/css/vendor/style.css  and  /public/js/vendor/jscript.js

Comment: Can you have 'public/Vendor/whatever' folders?

Comment: @deceze: indeed, I am aware of this. I could move the vendor directory in public... would that be considered a good practice? 
If I do not move the vendor directory, how could I rewrite the rule to redirect to public "and" allow the access to ~vendor ?

Comment: @Andy: with Deceze's answer, this is what I'm wondering. Also would it be a good practice to move it there?

Comment: Put it this way, I think it would be _bad_ practice to rewrite the rules when you can just add the Vendor folder to public (which is where I think it ought to go).

Comment: I do like that solution, it is easy to put in place and is also clean (I do love my code being clean and clear)! Thank you Andy and Deceze!

Comment: @Andy, if you wish to post your solution as an answer, I'll accept it gladly.

Comment: @Slyvain, I've added my comments as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest having either:

```
public/js/Vendor
public/css/Vendor
```

or

```
public/Vendor/js
public/Vendor/css
```

would be the best way to go. I think it would be bad practice to rewrite the rules when you can just add the Vendor folder to public (which is where I think it ought to go).

Answer (score 0):

The only code that should sit outside the public directory is Application level code, by the looks of it your PHP.

All other assets that are loaded by your server should live in the public directory, that's why it's called public, because it's accessible by the public through your webserver's requests.

An alternative would be to create a js-source directory at the root of the project and have a task manager like Grunt or Gulp compile and copy the js into your public directory, that would look something like this:

```
project-name/
  application/
    config/
    controllers/
    models/
    views/
  public/
    css/
    images/
    js/     <- is filled with js from js-source/ by grunt/gulp
    .htaccess
    index.php
  js-source/
    vendor/
    main.js  <- is uglified/concatinated & copied into public/js by grunt/gulp
.htaccess
```

Reference links:

- http://gruntjs.com/
- http://gulpjs.com/

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however the solution proposed by Andy worked perfectly.

Comment: No worries, if I wasn't using Grunt or Gulp I would do as Andy has suggested. However I thought it would be a good opportunity to suggest a more modern alternative, Gulp and Grunt are great tools which I highly recommend you look into, perhaps not on this project, but maybe the next.

Answer (score 0):

You could copy your htaccess from public library to your vendor library, so that it would override your root directory htaccess.